# why posts are not shown in home page?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-templates, django-urls

when I add a post in the admin panel, the posts are not shown on the home page of the app.
it only shows spaces of the post but couldn't show writeup of the post on the home page.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render,HttpResponseRedirect
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import SignUpForm, LoginForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from .models import Post
# Create your views here.

# home
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'blog/home.html',{'posts':posts})
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}

<div class="col-sm-10">
  <h3 class="text-white my-5">Home Page</h3>
    {% for post in posts %}
      <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbo-colour">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-bold">{{posts.title}}</h1>
          <p class="lead">{{posts.desc}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    desc = models.TextField()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a typo in your code. It should be:

```
{% for post in posts %}
  <div class="jumbotron jumbotron-fluid jumbo-colour">
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="display-4 font-weight-bold">{{post.title}}</h1>  // not posts.title
      <p class="lead">{{post.desc}}</p>  // not posts.desc
    </div>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```